# Is parent definition in API request body required if it's partial sub child properties are marked required?

Tags: swagger, openapi

Suppose I have the following OpenAPI definition (ignore the indentation or missing attributes):

```yaml
FooData:
  type: object
  additionalProperties: false
  description: Holds the foo data Information.
  required:
    - id
    - contact
  properties:
    id:
      description: Identifier
      type: string
      maxLength: 255
      minLength: 1
      pattern: ^[a-zA-Z0-9\-]{1,255}$
    identity:
      description: Holds customer identity info.
      $ref: '#/MyIdentity' ....

MyIdentity:
  type: object
  additionalProperties: false
  description: Holds the customer identity information.
  required:
   - userId
  properties:
    userId:
      type: integer
      format: int64
      minimum: 0
      maximum: 9223372036854775807
      description: Unique Identification Number which is specific to individual user.

    firstName:
      type: string
      description: user's First name.
      maxLength: 32
      minLength: 1
      pattern: ^[a-zA-Z\s]{1,32}$ ....
```

As you see, `MyIdentity` is not required in `FooData` however its property `userID` is marked as `required`.

Can we ignore the full `MyIdentity` object in the request body while hitting the API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the request body schema is `FooData`:

> Can we ignore the full `MyIdentity` object in the request body while hitting the API?

Yes - because the `FooData.identity` property is not required so it can be omitted. However, if the `FooData.identity` property is present, it must be an object and contain at least the `userId` property.

In other words, the following `FooData` payloads are valid:

```json
{
  "id": "abc",
  "contact": "..."
}

{
  "id": "abc",
  "contact": "...",
  "identity": {
    "userId": 12345
  }
}
```

but these payloads are invalid:

```json
// No `userId` in `identity`
{
  "id": "abc",
  ...,
  "identity": {}
}

// No `userId` in `identity`
{
  "id": "abc",
  ...,
  "identity": {
    "firstName": "Alex"
  }
}

// `identity` is not an object
{
  "id": "abc",
  ...,
  "identity": null
}

// `identity` is not an object
{
  "id": "abc",
  ...,
  "identity": "blah"
}
```